# Why can't I view the rest of my components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am working on this project, now everything on the server is running fine but I am having issues viewing the rest of the components for the web app of the page beside the header.

Here is the link to my codebase https://github.com/henry88lay/MyReads-Project

no errors or messages can't seem to find the bug

Comment: can you put it on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: i do not see `updateSearchedResult` defined anywhere in your code. so `this.updateSearchedResult`  should produce an error..

Comment: Also your code looks an awful lot like https://github.com/Decoys-out/MyReads

Comment: Yeah when I was going through the project for the last 2 days there were times when I got stuck. So I ended up googling other peoples project to see how other people took it on. As a result you can recognise that there is a lot of similarities in the process.